# Authentication required

Tags: authentication, ubuntu, permissions, root, superuser

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/reTqo.png)

Authentication is required to run '/bin/bash' as the super admin.
incorrect permissions on /usr/libexec/polkit-agent-helper-1 (needs to be setuid root)

Answer (score 0):

Open terminal and run:

```
sudo -i
chmod 4755 /usr/libexec/polkit-agent-helper-1
```

Then you should be prompted for sudo creds instead of the failure.